# How to use ORDER BY in SQL Server on a column of a table?

Tags: sql-server

We have a table like this:

```
bok jel str1    str2
1   3   184 185
1   3   215 219
1   3   229 244
1   3   267 273
1   3   331 331
1   3   338 339
```

we want sort by str1 and str2.

Comment: BUT how the accepted answer is an answer?

Comment: if that's the answer then the question needs to be edited to reflect the need for concatenation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM   YourTable
ORDER  BY str1,
          str2
```

Comment: note that it would also be a good idea to make sure that the table is indexed on those fields as well, otherwise your query might be slow.

Comment: @Andomar 5 pointer for `select * from ...` ?! I think if this had been a c# post there would have been about 20 posters referring the OPer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx). sql posters are friendly.

Comment: ok - I've seen that "community wiki" dotted about but never known what it actually is

Answer (score 1):

General practice is:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TEMP 
ORDER BY 
  STR1
  , STR2
```

Another possibility is ordering by `STR1 + STR2` but be aware that it will return different results . e.g [on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44506/4)

Answer (score 0):

```
Set NOCOUNT ON
select bok, jel, st1, st2 from YourTable order by str1, str2
```